# calling function inside chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension, and I have a background.js and a content_script.js. When the web page loads, I send a message to the content script to run a function; unfortunately it isn't behaving as expected. The code in question is in my content_script.js file, and it looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert("Test 1 2 3");
        welcome(tab);
    }
);
```

I have a function called `welcome(tab)` that takes the current tab as a parameter and performs some arbitrary functions. I know the message is being received because the `alert` always happens, but the `welcome` function is never executed. I know the `welcome` function works, I've done plenty of testing. Things stopped working when I added the `addListener`. Any suggestions? I've looked everywhere so far. Also, might it have to do with the addListener function not knowing what the global `tab` variable is?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the tab here. Have a look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert("Test 1 2 3");
        welcome(sender.tab);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, it still seems to not be working. If you're sure this is correct then i can check the code of the `welcome` function again.. but as of right not I added your edit and the `alert` still pops up, nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: @CameronPayton, I am not very sure about it either. But there are something need to be described: the parameter you required for the welcome function, is that the int (tab_id) or tab object or any other info about the tab?

Comment: you can use console.log(sender.tab) to find out the detail of this object and use the info you need from it.

Comment: It's the actual tab object itself (the welcome function uses tab.url and other methods)

Comment: I just did the console.log trick, I don't think sender.tab is sending a tab object into my welcome function, because it's throwing an error and saying "cannot read property 'url' of undefined at welcome"

Comment: @CameronPayton, what about the console.log(sender); Any detail info about "sender"?

Comment: That was it! Thanks Kelvin. What was happening was that the sender object wasn't the tab, but rather the extension object itself. So I set the request.message to be the url and changed my welcome function to take the url parameter instead of tab parameter.